# implementing a file deletetion function

Tags: php

I have a system, where users (even public) can upload *.pdf files,now I want to implement a feature which provides the ability to delete the uploaded files.

This is what I have in mind :

- create an unique delete hash for each file
  and store it in database ( associate
  it with unique id of each file )
- Generate and display the  delete url
  to the user who has uploaded the file
- When the delete url (Along with id
  and hash ) is called, check if the
  delete hash matches with the id
- unlink the file

is this system ok ? 
I just want to make sure the user can delete only the file which he has uploaded , but not other files.

Thanks

Edit :
Please suggest me a method to create a hash , which cannot be guessed .

Comment: na -1 is always easy to give, but it should be relevant, and you should give a reason: how do you intend to link files and users? A link is necessary, would it be a user-id, a cookie... Unless the user can only delete the file she *just* uploaded. In any case it should be mentioned in the question. My answer is relevant considering the context. The context is your question.

Comment: but I think that using a hash is must, as both guests and members can upload file, which I have mentioned in my question . And I seriously don't know the importance of this down voting system .

Comment: na But you seem to be using it...

Comment: I mean, I didn't know that members take it seriously..from next time I will think many times before down voting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your users have to authenticate to use your service, it might be better to keep track of the file's owner and only allow that user to delete it. If all your users are anonymous the above solution should work ok. I would question how good an idea it would be to let anonymous users upload files though...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you suggest me a method to generate some random and secure hash ?

Comment: `md5_file()` http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php -- though I still think you should do this with user authentication...

Comment: Well, everyone can run the md5 hash function on the downloaded file, right?

Comment: ya..thats what I was thinking..I will concatenate md5 hash  with some random string ,making it almost impossible to guess the url .